# Loopj. Get progress while downloading image using BinaryHttpResponseHandler

Tags: android, loopj

Thanks for such a wonderful library. Just wanted to know is there a way to get the progress or byte size downloaded while downloading big size images/files whith `BinaryHttpResponseHandler`.
Awaiting response.

Hoping to get sample code for using this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you have to do is override the OnProgress method :

```
@Override
public void onProgress(long bytesWritten, long totalSize) {
    long progressPercentage = (long)100*bytesWritten/totalSize;
}
```

Comment: This callback is always returning totalSize=1 in my case. I checked and the server is correctly returning a Content-Length header in the response body. Any idea what may cause this?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Comment: Please that onprogress didn't work on 1.4.8, I downloaded 1.4.6 and I can now use progress.